# How to take variables by reference in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, reference

```
var arr = [1, 5, 17];

for (let e of arr)
    e += 3; // Does nothing

arr.forEach(e => e += 3); // Does nothing

console.log(arr);
```

In the above code my aim was to set all elements to 0 (just as an example), yet, when I use `=` on the element variable, nothing changes. I suspect this is, because

One solution is `arr.forEach((e, i, a) => a[i] = 0);`, but this looks very suboptimal when compared to a simple `for` `of` loop. Also, I've heard that `arr.forEach` in general has worse performance.

Comment: what is the question about? clearing array, taking references of primitive values or performance of iterating?

Comment: @NinaScholz Having `e` be a reference, so I can edit it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const input = [1, 5, 17]
const output = input.map(e => 0)
console.log(output)
```

Comment: I have no idea why this works, but it does. Is there like an implicit `return`?

Comment: Using `Array.prototype.map()` is an `immutable` strategy which `returns` a brand new `Array` based on the original. The example above says `return` `0` for every `element`.

Comment: I see; doesn't this create an unnecessary copy, though?

Comment: I personally favour `immutable` programming but I realise your question was framed from a `mutable` perspective, in which case Nina’s suggestion of `fill()` might be more apt.

Comment: `Cloning` (creating a copy) is typically less error prone and more efficient for operations such as comparison than `mutating`. The performance costs are negligible. Such strategies are very necessary when using frameworks such as ReactJS. You can read resources such as [ImmutableJs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) to decide whether `immutability` is right for you. `map()` is a staple function regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
arr.forEach(e,i => arr[i] = 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for setting all items to the same primitive value, or with an object to the same reference, you could use [`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

```js
var array = [1, 5, 17];

array.fill(0);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: It's just as a simple example, it's not what I'm actually trying to do

Comment: please add what you are trying in the question

Comment: Is it better now?